# Passing Select box value to a php page in javascript on onchange of selectbox

Tags: javascript, php

I have a select box showing some date ranges like 'Today,Yesterday,Last week'. My task is to get the selected value and pass it to another php page. I have written a basic javascript function which gets the selected option and alerts the option.

Can anyone help me with this..

Here is the select box code and javascript function:

```
 <form action="" method="POST" name="daterangeform" id="datedangeform">
              <select class="select2_category form-control" name="selectdate" onChange="formaction($(this).val())"> 
              <option value="">Select a date range</option>
              <option value="Today">Today</option>
              <option value="Yesterday">Yesterday</option>
              <option value="Last week">Last week</option>
              <option value="Last 30 Days">Last 30 Days</option>
              </select>
              </form>
<script>
              function formaction(id)
              {
             var tid=id;
            alert(tid);
                            document.getElementById('daterangeform').action ="date.php";
            document.datedangeform.submit();
              }
              </script>
```

Comment: add a relocate function and concat your chosen value to the url so that you can retrieve it to the other page

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong form id. Change this line

```
document.getElementById('daterangeform').action ="date.php";
```

TO

```
document.getElementById('datedangeform').action ="date.php";`
```

***OR*** change the form tag id to

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST" name="daterangeform" id="daterangeform">
```

And you javascript function should be:

```
 function formaction(id)
 {
        var tid=id;
        var form =  document.getElementById('daterangeform');
        form.action = "date.php";
        form.submit();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

in php method="post" will post the values.

add submit button in your form.

then do this

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

echo $_POST['selectdate'];

}
```

Comment: I've done as u  said.. But m not getting the selected value in date.php.

Comment: then in action attribute add path to the date.php and add this code in that file.

Comment: Its working.. :) 
Also can i get the selected value in same page itself??